# The method getRGB(int, int) in the type BufferedImage is not applicable for the arguments (..)

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a TIFF image with some "out of order" detectors (with `null` columns of pixels), and a previous created Array with index of column and nb of pixel `null`.
I am trying to build a code that, scanning image, correct it applying a simple interpolation:

```
image.setRGB = ((row + numOfDetectors) + (row - 1)/ 2);
```

of neighboring pixels when find `null` pixel (reading the informations in Array list).

But I'm having a bit of problems with the `image.setRGB` method.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ArrayInterpolatorNew {


    // public static void main(String[] args) {
    private static void getPixelData(BufferedImage tif) {
        try { 

            String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println ("Current directory: " + currentDir);

            //read image file
            File file1 = new File("E:\\ByPass_PAN_C.tif");
            BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(file1);

            // Firstly get a pixel
            int pixelValue = image1.getRGB(tif.getWidth(), tif.getHeight());

            // Developer may get all the pixels
            int width  = tif.getWidth(null);
            int height = tif.getHeight(null);
            int[] result = new int[height*width];
            int offset;


            image1.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result, 0);

            //write file
            File file = new File("Resources/ByPass_PAN_C_interpol.tif"); // The file to save to.
            String format = "TIF"; // Example: "PNG" or "JPG"
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);


            final byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
            final int firstRow = 1;
            final int numOfDetectors = 1;
            int row = tif.getWidth();
            int col = tif.getHeight();
            //int[][] pixels = new int[w][h];

            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) 

                for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) 
                    //result[] = image.getRGB(row, col);

                    for(int J = 0; J < firstRow; J++) 
                    {   
                        if (row != J){
                            // set a pixel
                            image.setRGB(row, col, pixelValue);
                            //pixels[row] = [row][col];

                        if (row == J){
                            System.out.println("x,y: " + row + ", " + col + "num of Detectors: " + numOfDetectors);
                            //image.setRGB = ((row + numOfDetectors) + (row - 1)/ 2);
                            //tif.setRGB(pixelNoInterpol | pixelInterpol);

                        if (row == J && numOfDetectors > 20){
                            System.out.println("x,y: " + row + ", " + col + "num of Detectors: " + numOfDetectors + "then > 20");
                            image.setRGB(row, col, pixelValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(image, format, file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally { System.out.println("Images were written succesfully.");}  
                    System.out.println("rest of the code...");
                    }
            }  finally {
                }     
            }
}
```

Comment: exaclty which `getRGB` call makes parser complain??

Comment: We would see the problem easier if you are not truncating the error message. You could heighlight the line with the problem, too.

Comment: Eclipse give me error on :             image1.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
image1.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result, 0);
```

You are missing the last parameter, [`scansize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int)).
You can use the `width` as the `scansize`, so it would be:

```
image1.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result, 0, width);
```

Comment: why parser is complaining then? *The method getRGB(int, int) in the type BufferedImage is not applicable for the arguments (..)*

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was on that line, but now that I look to the BufferedImage documentation I think I see where's the compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature is wrong. It's either

```
getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)
```

> Returns an array of integer pixels in the default RGB color model
>   (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB color space, from a portion of the
>   image data.

or

```
getRGB (int, int)
```

You are using the incorrect argument list for getRGB:

```
image1.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result, 0);
```

try

```
 image1.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result, 0, scansize);
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

*you are getting pixelValue  of last cell.  so get every cell pixel*

```
  int x1 = image1.getWidth();
  int y1 = image1.getHeight();
        BufferedImage dummy = new BufferedImage(x1, y1, 13);//BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        for ( int rows = 0; rows < x1; rows++ ) {
             for ( int columns = 0; columns < y1; columns++ ){


                 int firstImg_Pixel = image1.getRGB( rows, columns );

                   //  dummy.setRGB(rows, columns, Color.red.getRed());
                 }
         }      

        // ImageIO.write(dummy, "jpeg", new File("D:\\Screenshots\\A-Image\\uuu.jpg"));
```

Comment: Thanks YAsh ..very usefull !!  Now I have error on COLOR of dummy.setRGB (rows, columns, Color.red.getRed());  .. want say you that the code will run on single SPOT image layer (PN, MS1, MS2, MS3, MS4), not RGB image.

Comment: And .. I am working with an Array (a .xml file previously parsed in "nb of column in image and nb of null pixels) and TIFF image in input, not two different images.

Comment: sorry .. is number of columns on x assis and number of pixels wrong. ( 300 1 
600 2 
900 3 
1200 4 ) 
It is an image generated from satellite. and sometimes happen some wrong detector. Now I have to correct that image taking information from an xml previously parsed.

Comment: in a row perticular column pixel is wrong, by iterating you can identify then what you want to do.

Comment: Right, so why do you change code in "if ( firstImg_Pixel != secondImg_Pixel ) {" ?? .. the if must apply interpolation when the iteration on every pixel meet the same number of column described in array parsed, and apply interpolation for the number of pixels described in the same array :